# Use of using to dispose resources

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to understand the ‘using’ statement better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133182/trying-to-understand-the-using-statement-better)

I've really read all other posts, but no one really answers my question.

This is my function that returns a table

```
        public DataTable ReturnTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mainConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();                             
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;    
                    SQL = " SELECT * from table";                        
                    cmd.CommandText = SQL;                                            
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }           
            return dt;
        }
```

what's the advantage of the previous against the following (the one that I always used prior to discover 'using'):

```
public DataTable ReturnTable()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mainConnectionString);
                con.Open();                             
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;    
                SQL = " SELECT * from table";                        
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;                                            
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                return dt;
            }
```

With the second, aren't con, cmd and da properly disposed?
Is there anything wrong with the second?

Thanks!

Comment: The connection object is the most important one to close or dispose since it holds physical database resources. It will not be closed until the GC finalizes the object in the second case if there is an exception. Disposing the command and the data adapter is a really good idea but not as critical.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything wrong with the second?

As long as you don't get an exception in your code, this will work the same way for `con`, since `Close()` and `Dispose()` are effectively the same *in this case*.  It will not dispose of `da` or `cmd` immediately, and will wait until they are garbage collected to free their resources.

That advantage of `using` is that your resource is still disposed even in the case of exceptions or early exit from the method (you adding a `return` in the middle of your method).

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is that the `using` pattern calls the `Dispose()` method on the `IDisposable` interface, guaranteeing that any cleanup logic *you may have missed* gets properly executed, even if an exception is thrown.

In practice, objects implementing `IDisposable` are holding onto *unmanaged* resources which get cleaned up when `Dispose()` is called.  So calling `Close()` may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're *not* the same. That's the whole *point* of `using`.

What happens if your code throws an exception? Those objects won't be disposed until the garbage collector happens to get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

"using" in in this case tries to implement the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern, which is especially useful when dealing with limited resources such as database connections.